# Return an array using `form_with`?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, formbuilder, form-with

In my view, I have several checkboxes, and I want to send back an array of which are checked. I have achieved this by writing the HTML myself, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it using `FormBuilder#check_box`.

#### What I have working

```html
<%= form_with model: @dog, local: true do |my_form| %>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"
           name="dog[breeds][]"
           value="labrador">
    Labrador
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"
           name="dog[breeds][]"
           value="husky">
    Husky
  </label>
    <%= my_form.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

This works perfectly: the `params` contain what I expect. If I check the "husky" box and submit, the "breeds" array contains "husky":

```rb
"dog"=>{"breeds"=>["husky"]}
```

But I want to know if there's a way to use `my_form.check_box` for this, instead of writing out the checkbox HTML myself.

#### What I've tried for `FormBuilder#check_box`

```html
<%= form_with model: @dog, local: true do |my_form| %>
  <label>
    <%= my_form.check_box 'breeds[]', value: 'labrador'%>
    Labrador
  </label>
  <label>
    <%= my_form.check_box 'breeds[]', value: 'husky'%>
    Husky
  </label>
  <%= my_form.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

This doesn't submit what I expect. In the `params`, no matter which boxes I check, the "breeds" array is always empty:

```rb
"dog"=>{"breeds"=>[]}
```

#### Is there a way to do use the `FormBuilder` helpers for what I'm trying to do?

It really seems like there should be, but I've not been able to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this like so:

```
<%= form_with model: @dog, local: true do |my_form| %>
  <% ['labrador','husky'].each do |breed| %>
      <%= my_form.check_box :breeds, {multiple: true}, breed%>
      <%= my_form.label :breeds, breed.titleize %>
  <%end%>
  <%= my_form.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

The signature for `check_box` is `(object_name, method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")`.

Since you are using the form builder the `object_name` can be omitted as it will be `my_form`.

So we pass:

- the method `:breeds`,
- the `options` `{multiple: true}` so that it creates a collection
- the `checked_value` will be the breed name.

[`ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper#check_box` Documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box)